# reset password works on localhost and not on web host

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a laravel project (maintenance of an existing project).
The reset password was not working.. I fixed the issue by changing the .env file on my localhost.
It was

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I changed it to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=email@mailtrap.io
MAIL_PASSWORD=the password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

It works fine on my localhost.. When I change the .env.example on bitbucket it still doesn't work and gives me the same error

```
Swift_TransportException in AuthHandler.php line 181:
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "noreply@igpastpapers.com" using 2 possible authenticators
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing `.env`?  Modifying the `.env.example` file won't do anything, it's just meant as an example which is safe to be saved to a VCS.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about, but I don't find the .env file in the repository

Comment: I'm new to bitbucket.. but I think I understand that .env is not accessible except by the repository master and whoever he gives the permission to..  Is this right?

Comment: It should never be added to the repository period.  It should be uploaded to the server manually (or via some CI process if desired).  Check this link out which will hopefully shed some more light on this for you... https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: @user3158900 That's so helpful.. I found the .env file on my host.. I get another error now that needs to be fixed.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change your .env file in your production code, NOT your .env.example file.  The .env.example is only setup so you can see the build of your .env file wherever you keep your version control code (Git, etc), without actually having the secure data shown.  Check this link out:

[Environment Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-variable-types)